# Functional Analysis(Normed Spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$  be the space of all complex valued square Riemann- integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with $2$- norm. Define the map $F:X\to X$  by $F(u)=v$ with $v(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{ u^2(s) ds}$, then show that $F$ is continuous (but not uniformly continuous)?

Any hint to the above problem ..A beginner in Functional Analysis !!

Comment: Take any two element $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ and corresponding $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ then consider the expression $v_2(t)-v_1(t)=\int_0^t\left[u_1(s)+u_2(s)\right]\times \left[u_2(s)-u_1(s)\right]\times \mathbb{d}s$. For continuity, show that as $u_1(t)\to u_2(t)$, $v_1(t)\to v_2(t)$ and to disprove show that the difference of $v_2(t)-v_1(t)$ depend upon choice of $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ use epsilon delta proof. Hard part is to do it with function rather than numbers.

Comment: disapprove uniform continuity*

Comment: @Mann It was not the task to prove continuity with respect to the topology of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

For $u,v\in X$ we have
\begin{align*}
\|Fu - Fv\|_2^2
&= \int_0^1|(Fu)(t) - (Fv)(t)|^2\,dt = \int_0^1\left|\int_0^t(u^2-v^2)\,ds\right|^2\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1\left|\int_0^t(u-v)(u+v)\,ds\right|^2\,dt\le\int_0^1\left(\int_0^t|u-v||u+v|\,ds\right)^2\,dt\\
&\le \int_0^1\left(\int_0^t|u-v|^2\,ds \right)\left(\int_0^t|u+v|^2\,ds \right)\,dt\\
&\le \|u-v\|_2^2\|u+v\|_2^2.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\|Fu - Fv\|_2\le \|u-v\|_2\|u+v\|_2\le\|u-v\|_2\big(\|u-v\|_2 + 2\|v\|_2\big).
$$
The continuity of $F$ follows from here.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination !! Continuity is clear and why its not uniformly continuous?(Since we can't choose a \delta for entire space ,its norm dependent )